# securely restoring an ecryptfs encrypted backup

Tags: encryption, backup, restore, ecryptfs

I'm using ecryptfs to backup the entire contents of my Ubuntu box to an external hard drive enclosure.  I've followed [this](http://www.unixmen.com/encrypt-directories-partitions-ecryptfs-linux/) guide and have things properly backing-up and encrypted as I want.

That's all well and good until I have to actually use the encrypted backup, and that's got me wondering.  In the event that I lose my entire primary hard drive, what files/info should I readily have access to in order to de-crypt my backup?  Besides the options used to setup the initial encryption, are these the only two things I need:?

- passphrase
- sig key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a backup, you might just need to remember the passphrase and the options you used to set up the encrypted folder, so everything in the example page you linked:

> To see the files again, just mount the directory with ecryptfs
>   filesystem.
>
> ```
> # mount -t ecryptfs /home/sk/unixmen/ /home/sk/unixmen/
>
> Select key type to use for newly created files:
> 1) tspi
> 2) passphrase
> Selection: 2 <---- Type 2 and press enter
> Passphrase:  <---- Enter the passphrase
> Select cipher:
> 1) aes: blocksize = 16; min keysize = 16; max keysize = 32
> 2) blowfish: blocksize = 8; min keysize = 16; max keysize = 56
> 3) des3_ede: blocksize = 8; min keysize = 24; max keysize = 24
> 4) twofish: blocksize = 16; min keysize = 16; max keysize = 32
> 5) cast6: blocksize = 16; min keysize = 16; max keysize = 32
> 6) cast5: blocksize = 8; min keysize = 5; max keysize = 16
> Selection [aes]: <---- Press Enter
> Select key bytes:
> 1) 16
> 2) 32
> 3) 24
> Selection [16]: <---- Press Enter
> Enable plaintext passthrough (y/n) [n]: <---- Press Enter
> Enable filename encryption (y/n) [n]: <---- Press Enter
> Attempting to mount with the following options:
> ecryptfs_unlink_sigs
> ecryptfs_key_bytes=16
> ecryptfs_cipher=aes
> ecryptfs_sig=5c116acdf1d0dd89
> Mounted eCryptfs
> ```

The `ecryptfs_sig` is derived from the passphrase, so is really just to verify you've entered the right passphrase, not really essential to the mount command.

I can't say I like the *"Add your passphrase in this file"* part of the automatic mount section, detracts from the security by having the passphrase in plain text. Your system can use eCryptFS & PAM to automatically mount encrypted folders on login, using your login passphrase to "wrap"/encrypt the eCryptFS key. See `man ecryptfs` & the man pages for it's tools, like `ecryptfs-setup-private`

Comment: I can confirm that this works; all I have to do is mount it (just like I do on my original system) in the same way; furthermore, all I need is my password.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I found a much nicer solution, after struggling with the above for a couple of hours.

```
sudo ecryptfs-recover-private
```

It's super simple to use, just run it and it will find your old private directory, then mount it in `/tmp` for you.

From the man page:

> ecryptfs-recover-private - find and mount any encrypted private directories
>
> This  utility  is  intended  to help eCryptfs recover data from their encrypted home or encrypted private partitions.  It is useful to run this from a LiveISO or a recovery image.  It must run under sudo(8) or with root permission, in order to search the filesystem and
>          perform the mounts.